# How to add markers after I do click or enter from an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, here-api

Hello I'd like to know how to add some markers after an user add his or her user ID and press enter or do click in a button. This is my code:
[Example](http://pastebin.com/0w9BeJzH)

However when I tried to access with this user code: 203650675652fb1d17e87829.55134042 everything crash. I'd like to know what I should change. This is my JS code for Add markers after Enter:

```
            var markers = [];


        /* Attach an event listener to the newly created marker
         * to show info bubble on click of the marker
         */
         for (var idx = 0; idx < locations.length; idx++) {
            loc = locations[idx];

            alert(loc.latitude);
            alert(loc.longitude);

            /* Create a marker on a specified geo coordinate*/
            var marker = new nokia.maps.map.Marker([loc.latitute, loc.longitude]);

            // add the standard marker to the map's object collection so it will be rendered onto the map
            markers.push(marker);

         }


        map.objects.addAll(markers);
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Within your `keypress` function, the  line `e.preventDefault();` means you can't enter text.
2. Looking at the response from http://thewetzone.pixub.com/web_services/getLocation.php?uid=203650675652fb1d17e87829.55134042 your PHP page is including extra `<script>` and `<noscript>` tags - this means that the response is not valid geoJSON.
3. To parse geoJSON, you can use the standard [geoJSON parser](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#geojson-parser__load-geojson-russia-data-using-ajax) that can be found on the HERE Maps Community Pages on Git Hub
4. If you don't want to use geoJSON, there is also a generic [AJAX example](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#load-marker-data-using-ajax__index) available

Comment: Thank you very much! With last example I did it!